# Add a migration path to Pro Web Masters from Super User

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

As of now we have

- 39 questions tagged [cms](https://superuser.com/tags/cms/synonyms)

[image]

- 14 questions tagged [joomla](https://superuser.com/tags/joomla/synonyms)

[image]

- 21 questions tagged [drupal](https://superuser.com/tags/drupal/synonyms)

[image]

- 22 questions tagged [wordpress](https://superuser.com/tags/wordpress/synonyms)

[image]

And the questions on the above and other web master related keep coming it. Right now, the questions are either closed as off topic - or migrated to Web Apps and then the folks there  migrate then them over to Pro Web Masters. This really isn't the best approach, and I really don't like any of the SE2.0 sites being [considered as a dumpyard](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1515/why-are-questions-off-topic-for-super-user-being-migrated-from-other-trilogy-site), I suggest the team to add an option for migration path to Pro Web Masters

Comment: +1 good suggestion (and congrats on reaching 10k)

Comment: Thanks @Nifle :) you aren't too far away from 10k either :)

Comment: We'll see about that. I start a new job on Thursday so my available time for hanging around SU will shrink.

Comment: Ah, I see. All best on your new job :) @Nifle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky because SU already has 5 destinations:

1. meta.su (meta site is always first target of all close as off topics)
2. stackoverflow
3. serverfault
4. webapps
5. gaming

**We don't ever want to show more than 5 here, because it gets overwhelming.**

Thus, in order to get webmasters on there, you'd have to make a case that we can kick one of the existing 5 off the list. Are you prepared to do that?

Comment: I respect your stand, however I think SU is a bit of an edge case here, since it is a catch all for a lot of topics. I honestly don't have an answer, but I can foresee that we might have more option for migration here then on other sites. I do however agree having 8 or 10 sites in there is pushing the limit, but Pro Webmaster would filter well as a 6th option. I can't foresee Unix or Ubuntu ever being added, but even Apple may need to be added because of iPod and iPad questions, and so would Andriod. The problem here is the content and type of questions compared to SO and SF for example.

Comment: @Diago - maybe in this case the best compromise would be to migrate to Server Fault?

Comment: What about an other radio? Too Windows-y?

Comment: @Diago: For this reason I suggest that [sites should be added to the destination shortlist based on the question tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags).

Comment: @Jan The problem has been resolved since diamond moderators can now migrate questions to any site. So the problem is actually not a problem any longer.

Answer (score 2):

Another one for the list - [MSFT crawling killing my linksys E3000](https://superuser.com/questions/213914/msft-crawling-killing-my-linksys-e3000)

Comment: not a pro webmasters question. No "pro" there. Running a website out of your house is squarely in Super User territory.

Comment: @Jeff I am not sure if it is running from his house. The indication is it is running from a business, however I do admit the description is vague and the OP needs to elaborate. It does however cross the thin line of a shopping recommendation.