# Please save this useful question

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, migration

my question was migrated from stackoverflow

[A Google approach to email](https://superuser.com/questions/234866/a-google-approach-to-email/)

I think its a really good question "Does Gmail show real data or is it fake or prediction?" and it might be useful for other people to know that in the future(i don't care about that myself since I already know that).

I have added "How to implement that feature in a web-app?" to make that question not closed as off-topic on SO, but they are not interested in hard questions and thats ok too.

I think its kind of a ok question for superuser(since 5 SO users do not want it). Maybe changing the body of the question would help?

Answer (score 6):

Your question should definitely not be here, so I wonder why they considered migrating it, see our FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about ...
>
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - ...
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> — [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)

So, given your question [Does Gmail show real storage size data or is it fake/prediction? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/234866/does-gmail-show-real-storage-size-data-or-is-it-fake-prediction-closed)
I would suggest that this question be moved back to either [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Given the answers, it could better fit on SO as it explains how it is programmed.
Given the initial question, it could better fit on P.SE or even better on [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

The part that has been done wrong on our side is that we think SO doesn't want it, but it actually does belong there as an on-topic question in the current form. But well, you got an answer so don't worry...

I'm voting for reopening and migration to SO.

Comment: I'll pitch in to help migrate... although web.apps might be a better place?

Comment: please migrate it to WebApps.

Comment: P.S. Could you also remove the comment "View source, dude", its a spam and its from new user who has never used SE sites(JS is a hard language to understand from source).

Comment: All I can do is flag the comment by hovering it and clicking the flag, try to do the same and it might disappear. Or... When a moderator like @IvoFlipse passes along to do this all at once. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to TomWij's answer perhaps a migration to Web Apps might be a better suited area:

> Web Apps - Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications. If your question generally covers …
>
> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
> Bookmarklets
> Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc)

*P.S. It's kinda annoying that Super User has become the "dumping grounds" for unliked Stack Overflow questions.*

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1515/why-are-questions-off-topic-for-super-user-being-migrated-from-other-trilogy-site & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66178/why-are-questions-off-topic-for-super-user-being-migrated-from-other-trilogy-site

Comment: The problem with SO is that too many people have hammers and when you have a hammer you just wait for chance to use it. Superuser has always been the "dumping grounds", it was the first extra site(SF doesn't count since its about almost nothing). personally I'm shocked they have migrate it and not just close it, but that shows that the question is valuable even for closers.

Comment: The problem there is the volume, I think. While 5 close votes suffices on sites like these, I don't think that 5 close votes on sites like Stack Overflow are a good chosen value. You obviously have more people that pass and thus vote. Or... Another voting system which has been suggested on Programmers.SE might be a solution, as that site has drawn quite some attention from SE.

Answer (score 3):

If it was migrated to Web Apps, it would be deleted across the board. Any question bounced to more than one site belongs to no sites. At least without serious editing and honing in on a question. And your example is in bad need of such work.

The question is neither useful or on topic for Super User. Migrating it here was a bad decision of the Stack Overflow closers.

> How to implement that feature in a web-app?

What feature? Cloud storage or updating numbers? Your question is vague and low quality.

Comment: In that case, the carpets do not match the drapes at all @tom

Comment: Does Gmail show real storage size?; How do you create a live incrementing counter?; They may be related by inspiration, but they are not the same question @tom

Comment: @TomWij I have to be honest, you spend so much time trying to prove a point, that in the end, most of us stop listening. I repeat what Jeff said, **the asker is responsible for asking a high quality question**. The community does enough, and as moderators, we have enough other issues to deal with. This is one **bad** question, and with all the storm in a teacup it has created, I am very close to hitting the delete button on it.

Comment: Thanks for summarising my answer :)

Comment: +1 @Diago: In the past, I stopped any discussion on both questions because I learned my misconception.  Now, I totally agree with [this comment](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1910/please-save-this-useful-question/1920#comment-4103) as I didn't know an automatic suspension system for downvotes exist, together with flagging the user if his user history reveals that he doesn't learn this makes a lot of sense which means the problem isn't there anymore (at least for me).